# Payment successful status changed to cancel in magneto

Tags: php, magento, payumoney, payu

I am using **PayU Payment Gateway**,if payment successful the  status is changed to cancel.How can I solve this? I have frequently faced this issue. How to change the order history in magento

Comment: Get connected with PayU tech support team.

Comment: Actually the payment is done but the order status is going to cancel.